# React Component OR React PureComponent

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I want to know when should I be using a **React Component** and when should I be using **React PureComponent**?

**Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

**PureComponent:**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
```

Can I use React PureComponent everywhere?

**OR**

is it safe to use **shouldComponentUpdate** and check and return **false** of not required

I just read an article stating that using pure components actually cause more harm than good. they recommend using "react-update-if-changed". How much true is this?

Article: https://hackernoon.com/react-purecomponent-considered-harmful-8155b5c1d4bc

Comment: `React.PureComponent` implements `shouldComponentUpdate` with a shallow prop and state comparison. It is an optimization tool that you can use if you really need it. `If your React component’s render() function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a performance boost in some cases.`

Comment: @Tholle is PureComponents harmfull anyway?

Comment: Not nessecarily harmful, but it can introduce subtle bugs, [as explained here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). I would personally just use `PureComponent` when there is a specific case in my app that could need it, not use it by default.

Comment: @tholle I think it's better to make container components has a PureComponents rather than lower level components because if props and states have not changed then the lower level components are anyway not gonna be reached.

Comment: If you haven't yet, read up on React performance. If you're careful with your data, React is already fast in just about every case and you will almost never need React.PureComponent.

Comment: @maccambridge what about complex scenarios, dont you think using PureComponents is gonna give a little performance boost.

Comment: a pure component only does a shallow comparison. So for deep mutations shouldComponentUpdate() would be a better choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I use React PureComponent everywhere?

Yes, you can but trying using Functional component more and more. In case of Class component, keep it small and extend it to PureComponent or Component if you want to implement your own shouldComponentUpdate, would advise to do it when, on minimal non complex (nested deep array or/and object) props change your component needs to update.

> Is it safe to use shouldComponentUpdate?

Yes, it is, if you know what you are doing, meaning that any flaw in your implementation, could lead to performance issues like unnecessary component re rendering just because your implementation of shouldComponentUpdate returned true or worse, that your component doesn't rerender on certain props change as your shouldComponentUpdate returns false due to some glitch.

The referenced medium post is trying to sell out react-update-if-changed package which seems like a good deal to go for at start but when you realize that

> the real problem statement is all about performance optimization (refer https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html)

How to avoid unnecessary checks to determine component can update and avoid unwanted rerender ?

- **Pass props** to component which you know is **needed** by the component and is going to **change**
- In case, if there are **many props** being send to a component and on very **few limited props change, the component needs to update** and re render then you could very well **implement your own shouldComponentUpdate** (refer the example in the above shared link of react optimization). But be wary of props which are arrays and object, as differentiating them is a pain, especially the deep bulky nested ones.
- Use a [**Functional (pure & stateless) component**](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc) for your UI while for it's presentation logic (show-hide, sort, etc) would be present in a components which would be a [**Class (stateful and pure by extending it to React.PureComponent) having children prop as a function**](https://medium.com/merrickchristensen/function-as-child-components-5f3920a9ace9); with the help of [**HOC**](http://refer%20https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) linking the logical and UI component
- Do use the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) while trying to pass props between ancestor and descendant, especially if they are a level beyond like grand parent component to child component.

Using the last method which is all about [**Advanced React Patterns**](https://medium.com/@jonatan_salas/advanced-react-patterns-lets-talk-about-render-props-function-as-child-and-hocs-c0cc4b5d6797) is the best way to have optimized performance and codebase. To understand it better, please refer [Dumb and Smart Components](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43) and [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: yeah sure, why not when it is indeed a very question, after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
export default Class PureComponent  extends React.PureComponent{
}

import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default Class NormalComponent  extends React.Component{
}
```

**PureComponent  Don’t have any Lifecycle Methods**

```
PureComponent check shallow comparison and re-render when Needed
Use Pure Component when used when primitive data types int string boolean etc,
```

**Note:-**

- PureComponent Don’t have any Lifecycle Methods
- React PureComponent's shouldcomponentupdate() only shallowly compares the objects.